# Format a USB Drive CDFS to NTFS

Tags: usb, partitioning, ntfs, wipe

I have some USB Drives that came pre-programmed. They are read-only and are being loaded as a CD Drive (ISO9660 / CDFS).  I cannot format the drives via the standard "right-click >> format".  I have been on the Internet trying to figure out a way to make these drives viable again, formatting them to FAT32 or NTFS, but can't find anything about how to do it.

I have tried using Windows CLI and other wipe programs, but none of them will recognize the drive as USB to give me the option to format or wipe it.

This is the controller information for my drive:

```
Volume: E:
Controller: Micov MW8209(MXT6208E) R
Possible Memory Chip(s): Not available
Flash ID: 2CAC9026
Flash CE: 1
VID: 1221
PID: 3234
Manufacturer: USB
Product: Disk
Query Vendor ID: USB
Query Product ID: Disk
Query Product Revision: 2.60
Physical Disk Capacity: 2103443456 Bytes
Windows Disk Capacity:  0 Bytes
Internal Tags: DJ2P-TH5L
USB Version: 2.00
Declared Power: 100 mA
ContMeas ID: 90FD-03-00
Microsoft Windows 10 x64 Build 16299
```

[DISKPART CMD Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9wEI.jpg)

[Disk Management Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p6Gv.jpg)

Comment: Can diskpart see this device as disk?

Comment: No, diskpart is not helpful at all.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Disk Management. Clarify what you tried with `diskpart` and how it failed.

Comment: I have added said images to my post.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, you won’t be able to recycle this USB drive. As Tonny’s answer correctly states, your only chance is with a firmware hack. However, that’s really just not worth it.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and would normally agree and just go buy a new one.  However I wanted to exhaust all effort to do this because we have about 100 of these drives (all from the same source) that if we could reformat them it would be beneficial to us so as to use as "throw away" drives for projects and what-not.  Otherwise I would not have embarked down this rabbit hole.

Comment: I have seen a recommendation for [UFDUtility](https://www.usbdev.ru/files/ite_tech/ufdutility/) formatting such disks. The site is in Russian but the software and manual are in English.

Answer (score 2):

That is not going to work.
The device presents itself to the computer as a USB connected CD-drive with a (read-only) CD-disc stuck in the drive. And Windows will only let you operate commands on that CD that are valid for CD-drives.

A USB CD-drive is a totally different type of USB device as a USB connected (hard)disk.
A (hard)disk can be re-partioned and re-formatted, but a CD-drive can't.

In some (very rare) cases the USB-chip inside the drive can be re-programmed to change its identity from CD-player to harddisk, but that requires a special program that is specific to that particular USB chip.
There is no such thing as a generic way to do that.

Comment: This is what I thought, but wasn't 100% sure because I hadn't setup or used this type of imaging and was getting conflicting information.  Would it help if I had the name of the controller?

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible that they have a special firmware (that appears as a CD storage device) loaded on the stick along with the CD image. As such you would need to identify the drive, and then locate an identical but non-readonly drive from which to copy the firmware for the USB flash controller.

Even that is non-trivial because you also probably need whatever firmware programming tool is required for that particular manufacturer of USB stick. These are not likely to be "standard" tools, but custom for every manufacturer and maybe every controller.

Given the fast paced and varied world of memory sticks, all fighting to reach the lowest manufacturing cost while retaining some level of profit, there are likely to be hundreds of different controllers. All of those controllers are going to have tens or hundreds of different firmwares depending on the flash chip, the flash size, the configuration, speed settings and a whole raft of other options.

You'll drive yourself insane spending weeks or more trying to resurrect a 1GB memory stick, purchasing various similar looking dodgy aftermarket sticks, all when you can buy eight 8GB sticks for $20 off Ebay and chuck out the useless piece of plastic.

Or it could just be that you need to fire up a Linux LiveCD to delete and recreate a sensible partition table.

Comment: I have added my drive controller and other information to my post, if it helps.  Can you guide me to how I might re-create a partition table using Linux?

Comment: If you are able, then simply run gparted, select the drive and then delete and recreate partitions. There appears to be some USB repair tools for your controller at http://www.flashdrive-repair.com/2013/11/Update-Ameco-MW8209-firmware-and-fix-corrupted-flash-drive.html but I've never used that site nor the tools. Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=Micov+MW8209

Comment: Just tested with GNU/Linux and `gparted`. It does not work. Just like Microsoft Windows, GNU/Linux sees this as 2 devices: a CD-ROM and a USB-storage device. Thus you can only edit the partition on the USB-storage device.